# "No newline at end of file" compiler warning

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, warnings, c-preprocessor

What is the reason for the following warning in some C++ compilers?

> No newline at end of file

Why should I have an empty line at the end of a source/header file?

Comment: Not really the reason, but it's very annoying if you `cat` a file and it does not have a trailing newline as the new shell prompt will appear after the last line of the file (i.e. not in column 0)

Comment: @ThiefMaster My $PS1 starts with a newline for that very reason. (it's a multi line prompt anyway, containing a bunch of useful info on one line and then nothing but a prompt character on the next so that fairly long commands don't wrap)

Comment: `Why should I have an empty line at the end of a source/header file` - If a text file contains `one\ntwo\nthree\n` then it contains three lines, none of which is empty. If a text file contains `one\ntwo\nthree` then it is not a text file, in the same sense that a sentence without a full stop at the end is not a sentence.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Think of some of the problems that can occur if there is no newline. According to the ANSI standard the `#include` of a file at the beginning inserts the file exactly as it is to the front of the file and does not insert the new line after the `#include <foo.h>` after the contents of the file. So if you include a file with no newline at the end to the parser it will be viewed as if the last line of `foo.h` is on the same line as the first line of `foo.cpp`. What if the last line of foo.h was a comment without a new line? Now the first line of `foo.cpp` is commented out. These are just a couple of examples of the types of problems that can creep up.

---

Just wanted to point any interested parties to James' answer below. While the above answer is still correct for C, the new C++ standard (C++11) has been changed so that this warning should no longer be issued if using C++ and a compiler conforming to C++11.

From C++11 standard via James' post:

> A source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to the file (C++11 §2.2/1).

Comment: Of course in practice every compiler adds a new line after the #include.  Thankfully.

Comment: I recall an old version of Microsoft Visual C++ (like 2.x or something) had exactly this problem. It was exacerbated because the IDE editor encouraged this sort of missing-newline behaviour.

Comment: Compilers may not complain currently, but GitHub actually does.

Comment: I can see the ["below" answer by James](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8172348/303290) but: "The above answer" in OrderBy what?! Above is the question, as I usually order by votes. Or do you mean your own answer?

Comment: @Thomas: Is this program invokes undefined behavior because it doesn't end with new line. See program here: http://ideone.com/jswwf9

Answer (score 50):

The requirement that every source file end with a non-escaped newline was removed in C++11.  The specification now reads:

> A source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to the file (C++11 §2.2/1).

A conforming compiler should no longer issue this warning (at least not when compiling in C++11 mode, if the compiler has modes for different revisions of the language specification).

Comment: That's all well and good for C++; unfortunately, C still says it's UB, even in the latest draft of the upcoming C1X standard.

Comment: This question is tagged [c++] and not [c].

Comment: Even so, it probably *should* be tagged [c], since many people searching for this warning in C will find their way here.

Comment: This is still a good point to add. Adding this up above. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 30):

C++03 Standard [2.1.1.2] declares:

> ... If a source file that is not empty does not end in a new-line character, or ends in a new-line character
>   immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 16):

The answer for the "obedient" is "because the C++03 Standard says the behavior of a program not ending in newline is undefined" (paraphrased).

The answer for the curious is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-07/msg01120.html.

Comment: Ahh, the beloved "undefined behaviour". When other languages fail, c/c++ behave in "undefined" ways :) That, certainly, is a big part of their charm. And I am not kidding.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't referring to a blank line, it's whether the last line (which can have content in it) is terminated with a newline.

Most text editors will put a newline at the end of the last line of a file, so if the last line doesn't have one, there is a risk that the file has been truncated. However, there are valid reasons why you might not want the newline so it is only a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 6):

`#include` will replace its line with the literal contents of the file. If the file does not end with a newline, the line containing the `#include` that pulled it in will merge with the next line.

Answer (score 3):

> Of course in practice every compiler adds a new line after the #include. Thankfully. –  @mxcl

not specific C/C++ but a C dialect: when using the `GL_ARB_shading_language_include` extension the glsl compiler on OS X warns you **NOT** about a missing  newline. So you can write a `MyHeader.h` file with a header guard which ends with `#endif // __MY_HEADER_H__` and you **will** lose the line after the `#include "MyHeader.h"` for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I am using c-free IDE version 5.0,in my progrm either of 'c++' or 'c' language i was getting same problem.Just **at the end of the program** i.e. last line of the program(after braces of function it may be main or any function),**press enter**-line no. will be increased by 1.then execute the same program,it will run without error.

Answer (score 2):

Because the behavior differs between C/C++ versions if file does not end with new-line. Especially nasty is older C++-versions, fx in C++ 03 the standard says (translation phases):

> If a source file that is not empty does not end in a new-line
>   character, or ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a
>   backslash character, the behavior is undefined.

Undefined behavior is bad: a standard conforming compiler could do more or less what it wants here (insert malicous code or whatever) - clearly a reason for warning.

While the situation is better in C++11 it is a good idea to avoid situations where the behavior is undefined in earlier versions. The C++03 specification is worse than C99 which outright prohibits such files (behavior is then defined).

Comment: I suspect the Standard said that programs without the trailing new-line have Undefined Behavior, rather than stating that they were ill-formed, because some compilers would concatenate a non-terminated final line of an included file with the source code text following the `#include` directive, and some programmers targeting such compilers may have exploited such behavior.  Having the Standard leave such things Undefined would allow programs exploiting such quirks to be well-defined on platforms which specify such behavior.  Having the Standard mandate a behavior would break such programs.

Answer (score 0):

This warning might also help to indicate that a file could have been truncated somehow.  It's true that the compiler will probably throw a compiler error anyway - especially if it's in the middle of a function - or perhaps a linker error, but these could be more cryptic, and aren't guaranteed to occur.

Of course this warning also isn't guaranteed if the file is truncated immediately after a newline, but it could still catch some cases that other errors might miss, and gives a stronger hint to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use KOTLIN Language and the compiler is on IntelliJ. Also, I am using a docker container with LINT to fix possible issues with typos, imports, code usage, etc. This error is coming from these lint fixes, most probably - I mean surely.

In short, the error says, 'Add a new line at the end of the file' That is it.

[image: Added Line on the file at the END]

Before there was NO extra empty line:

[image: Without new line on the file]