# what is the meaning of "warning : No new line at end of file"?

Tags: c, windows, linux, gcc, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No newline at end of file” compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271/no-newline-at-end-of-file-compiler-warning)

i am a Linux user and use gcc at work But at home i have installed cygwin package and using its `gcc` on my windows machine.

when ever i make any .c file and run its shows following warning

```
Warning : No new line at end of file
```

when i add extra new line at the end of that c file warning disappeared.
i haven't faced such warning while working with gcc in Linux.

so

**why i am getting this warning? what does it mean ?**

**Edit**

Whats the need or whats the advantage of doing this ?

if it is part of c programming standard then why it doesnt give any error while working in linux ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271/no-newline-at-end-of-file-compiler-warning (that question is about C++).

Comment: Well it means that there is no new line at the end of the file...

Comment: after my edit it not duplicate with that question

Comment: Why it is a good habit to leave a line at the EOF is when you include header files say the statement was #include "header.h"extern int a; This could lead to errors as tokens will get tangled.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C language requires that every source file must end with a newline (from C99 5.1.1.2/1):

> A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.

(C++ also had this requirement prior to C++11)

Comment: have you seen anywher in c language standard draft ?

Answer (score 1):

[No newline at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271) shows why you are getting this error and why it may be bad not to have a newline.

You are probably not getting this at work because whatever editor you use at work is probably adding newlines at the ends of text lines and the editor you're using at home isn't.

Comment: @Mr.32, you can control whether Vim adds or does not add newlines with `:set binary`.

Comment: @DourHighArch: it's `set binary noeol`.