# PHP: Is there a reason to put a newline at the end of file

Tags: php, coding-style, newline, git-commit

When I commit a php file to github I get the message "No newline at end of file".

It's just a warning and I remember, that for any reason it is good to have a newline at the end of a file.

But why? Is it a remnant of long gone times, does it still have advantages or is it even required in php? If yes, for what reason?

Comment: it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Is it a *warning* or simply a *statement* in the diff view?

Comment: Just a statement I guess. It's just when it came to my mind again. I thought there was a reason to do it in PHP.

Comment: Stupid GIT confused me too. It should say "no blank line at end of file", but it says "No newline at end of file".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not required by PHP, but it can cause problems with some diff tools.  The warning is a just a warning and can be ignored if desired, but I would recommend following convention and having the last character be a newline.

Answer (score 29):

This is a [PSR-2 convention](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#22-files) that states:

> All PHP files MUST end with a single blank line.

Why? Because utilities that are supposed to operate on files (like the [diff utility](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)) may not cope well with lines that don't end with a newline; this is how [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) states in one of its [rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206):

> 3.206 Line
>
> A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a
>   terminating  character.

Therefore, lines not ending in a newline character aren't considered actual lines. Which means: if your last line is a line of code (instead of an empty line), it might be ignored by those tools and can cause your program to break!

Comment: You are living in the past, [PSR-12 #2.2 Files](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files) Quote: `All PHP files MUST end with a non-blank line`

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Why has this recommendation been changed?

Comment: He confuses PSR's and the question about the origin that lead PSR's to include this recommendation...

Comment: @Yevgeniy Afanasyev: You quoted literally **HALF** of the requirement.  Read the *entire* sentence, please!  `All PHP files MUST end with a non-blank line, terminated with a single LF.`, yes, TERMINATED with a single Line-Feed, so, no: 1) user is not living in the past, and 2) the requirement is unchanged. (P.S. Great answer, thanks!)

Answer (score 10):

Now, in [PSR-12 #2.2 Files](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files):

> All PHP files MUST use the Unix LF (linefeed) line ending only.
>   All PHP files MUST end with a non-blank line, terminated with a single LF.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is to help you to detect a possibly defective, truncated file, on the assumption that file without a newline at the end is suspect for being truncated.

Other than that, the only reason to avoid source files without a terminating newline is to avoid the warning!

Comment: Usefull to know: Truncated files can occur for example when data or a data stream (such as a file) is stored in a location too short to hold its entire length.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably derived from the C standard: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.1.2.html (paragraph 123). Reasons include that some compilers or other text text processing tools process the source code line by line thus also the last source line has to end with a new-line character.

Also see this: ["No newline at end of file" compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271/no-newline-at-end-of-file-compiler-warning) - `include`ing a file without new line at the end could cause similar problems like in C.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason to add new lines everywhere is **git** history.
Let's say you don't add an empty newline in the end of the file, at first the "Git blame" says it is **you** who wrote that last line.

If somebody else now wants to add a new line in the end. He MUST change your last line, there is no way around. He has to add a \n and then add his new code... So his name is now on your line only to add a simple \n

[image: git says 2 lines changed by adding only one]

Comment: Very clear and useful example why you should want to always write a newline at the end of a file, altho this is true independent of php.