# New line at the end of XML files. Performance on Android devices?

Tags: java, android, newline

Java has some [specification](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-113) that states:

> Some tools work better when files end with an empty line.

By researching, I have found that it refers only to text files.

What about XML files? Do they need a new line at the end?

- When I add in Android Studio some vector asset, in that XML file a **new line is automatically added** at the end.
- However when creating a new layout file there is **no new line** at the end of the file.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/10082297)? It doesn't address Android specifically but I think it covers enough to infer.

Comment: Also I would like to mention that as far as I'm aware *Java* doesn't have any such *specification*. The link you provided is from a separate entity.

Comment: Hey @HenryTwist, yes i have read it. And when go throught answers in that topic, then it could be find, that [C++ has a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271/no-newline-at-end-of-file-compiler-warning) if no empty line is on the end. Java is inspired from C++ and has similar syntax. All java files have new line on EOF per default. So this answer for `xml` files is not clear enought to be sure.